# Where are the people writing "would of" from?

Tags: pronunciation, errors, weak-forms

As a non-native speaker, I would never have guessed that this mistake was a thing before I read it on the web.

Since it makes no grammatical sense, I can guess that it can only be seen in the writing of native speakers because they have learned the language through oral communication, while most non-native are exposed to written English from the very beginning of their learning.
I also guess the accent may influence the appearance of this error, and thus I am wondering, where are these people from?

Is it more of an American English thing? More British English? Something else?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133825/discussion-on-question-by-wip-where-are-the-people-writing-would-of-from).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to the following blog post by American  linguist [Lynne Murphy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynne_Murphy), the mistaken use of “would of” appears to be both British and American:

> I read ***of*** instead of ***'ve*** a lot in my British students' essays. A lot. There's no reason to think they're getting it from American influence, because they'd have to read it and they probably don't get the chance to read a lot of misspel{ed/t} American English. The American books or news they read will have (we hope) been proofread. I suspect that errors like this aren't learn{ed/t}from exposure at all: they are re-invented by people who have misinterpreted what they've heard or who have a phonetic approach to spelling, sounding out the words in their minds as they write.

(Lynne Murphy, Feb 4, 2016. "[might of, would of, could of, should of](https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2016/02/might-of-would-of-could-of-should-of.html)", *Separated by a Common Language: Observations on British and American English by an American linguist in the UK*)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133826/discussion-on-answer-by-user-66974-where-are-the-people-writing-would-of-from).

Answer (score 14):

Spellings like "would of", which are considered erroneous, occur in both American and British English, and probably, as [Dan Bron's comment says](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/584008/where-are-the-people-writing-would-of-from#comment1459779_584008), everywhere.

The reason for the spelling is that *of* and *have* have the same pronunciation in this context: /əv/ or /ə/.

This pronunciation is what English language teachers call a "[weak form](https://multimedia-english.com/phonetics/weak-vs-strong-forms)", meaning it is a pronunciation that occurs only when the word is unstressed. Many common grammatical words in English have weak forms with the vowel /ə/, and strong forms with a different vowel. Another example is *to,* with the weak form /tə/ and the strong form /tu/ (rhyming with *do,* and homophonic to *two* and *too*). The strong form of "have" is /hæv/, with the same vowel sound as "hat" or "cat". The strong form of "of" is /ɒv/ in British English; in American English, the strong form of "of" is usually /ʌv/.

Michael Harvey's comments saying that "of" rhymes with the first syllable of "hover" are referring to the strong form. However, I doubt that anyone habitually uses the strong form of *of* in this context. I would only expect to hear "of" in a strong form here in the artificial context of somebody who is reading out loud and making an effort to make "would of" sound distinct from "would have".

Comment: Re your last paragraph: I’m pretty sure I’ve occasionally heard *would of* pronounced with the strong *of* by native BrE speakers, in contexts where the phrase was heavily emphasised — something like “Didn’t he?  I really would of!” — contexts where another speaker might say it with the strong form of *have*.  Which doesn’t seem surprising — the spelling strongly suggests its users have reanalysed *would /əv/* as *would of*, and so in contexts that elicit the strong form, it’s the strong form of *of* that comes out.

Answer (score 5):

I see it frequently in America.  It’s a homonym of the contraction *would’ve*, and similarly, other modal verbs like *could’ve*, *should’ve*, *must’ve* and *might’ve*.  There is, however, no **can’ve* or **will’ve* in standard written English.  I personally don’t contract *can have* that way in speech, or at least not as often, but do contract *will have*.  I’m not sure, but this might be because I do sometimes say things like “can of beans” and very rarely “will of the people,” whereas the closest thing to *would* that I might follow with the preposition *of* is something like, “the wood of a sturdy tree.”  So perhaps I subconsciously pronounce “can have” more distinctly from “can of.”

With negative contractions, *won’t’ve* and *wouldn’t’ve* are so rare that my spell checker doesn’t recognize either, but I pronounce the word *have* in *wouldn’t have* the same way as in *would have*, when they’re both stressed or both unstressed.

Another variant is “Woulda, coulda, shoulda,” or “Wooda cooda shooda,” which writes out phonetically an even more-reduced form of unstressed *have*. This is more informal than “Would’ve, could’ve, should’ve.”  Be careful: other particles can be reduced the same way, so “canna” would be read as “cannot” or “playa” as “player.”

Since there are many verb phrases that do use *of* (for example, “Be of service”), **would of* is an easy mistake for native speakers to make.  It’s likely to become an accepted synonym of *would have* eventually, but is still considered an error by people of my generation.

Comment: won’t’ve and wouldn’t’ve

Comment: @philipxy I honestly cannot recall ever having seen either of those spellings before.

Comment: I can't imagine any other spelling; this is how contractions work. I expected your spellings were typos. A quick browse of sites of published dictionaries shows that if they have these words, they're spelled per my comment.

Comment: @philipxy that's certainly the sensible spelling, but I don't think I've ever seen them in writing except possibly in dialogue. Where I'd say "won't've" I'd write "won't have" and I reckon most people would do the same

Comment: @philipxy A quick search shows that those spellings do occasionally appear, from 1920 onwards. They’re very rare.

Comment: Maybe not can've, how about can't've?  @philipxy >> this is how contractions work:  but you seem to have no problem with '[can't](https://thepaleographer.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/lewis-carroll-his-critics-and-his-apostrophes/)'?  Style guides generally say not to use double-contracted words in writing if you can help it.

Comment: @mcalex I've  seen  multiple apostrophes in contractions like "sha'n't"  -- in the Lewis Carroll book I grew up with, printed around 1920. Apostrophes are dying out. Try getting  a spell checker to accept that a word can end with an apostrophe!

Comment: *_Can have_ doesn't occur, so *_can've_ doesn't either. Epistemic _can_ only occurs in a negative environment, hence _can't have_ or _can't've_ is OK, though it'd be pronounced same as _can't of_. All modals have idiosyncratic contractions and meanings, especially when involving negation.

Comment: @JohnLawler In my dialect, it sometimes does.